# Show that $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{<p(x)>}$ has a solution of $p(x)= x^3 - 6x +2 =0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Consider $p(x)= x^3 - 6x +2$.

I first proved that it's irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then I concluded that $<p(x)>$ is a maximal ideal so that $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{<p(x)>}$ is a field.

After that, I was asked to show that $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{<p(x)>}$  has a solution of $p(x)= x^3 - 6x +2 =0$.

My prof. answered this way:

Let $<p(x)> =I$,

$p(x)\in I$ so $p(x) +I = I$ i.e. $x^3 - 6x +2 +I = 0+I$, so

**$(x+I)^3 - 6(x+I) +2+I = I$** so $x+I$ is a root of $p(x)$ in $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{I}$. How did he add $I$ to the equation?? I got stuck at this point and tried alot to understand it alone :( Thanks for any help.

Comment: If $R$ is a ring and $I$ is an ideal, what is the _definition_ of the quotient ring $R/I$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $\frac{R}{I}$ is the ring that contain cosets under cosets addition and multiplication, i.e. $\frac{R}{I}=$ { $r+I ; r\in R$}. So what?

Comment: @Nour so $x+I$ is a member of $R/I$

Comment: @KennyLau so $x+I$ is a solution of the equation in $\frac{R}{I}$? Sorry if I'm asking a question with a trivial answser, but I really can't see the way.

Comment: Right. So in particular the elements of $R/I$ are things of the form $r+I$, where $r\in R$. That answers your question about why he "added the $I$"! He didn't add anything, he's just writing carefully, referring to a certain element of $\mathbb Q[x]/I$.

Comment: By definition $(a+I)+(b+I)=(a+b)+I$ and $(a+I)(b+I)=ab+I$. Using these definitions, what does $(x+I)^3 - 6(x+I) +(2+I) $ reduce to?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $(x+I)^3 - 6(x+I) +2+I = x^3 +I -6x +I +2+I= x^3-6x+2 +I= I$? So we have $x$, a solution in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $x+I$, a solution in $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{I}$, so he added $I$ to suit the new ring which's the quotient ring.Right?

Comment: Right, $x+I$ is a solution in $\mathbb Q[x]/I$. No, $x$ is _not_ a solution in $\mathbb Q[x]$. Btw it's not important, but the notation is $R/I$, not $\frac RI$...